# How to add conditionals to two tables in Google Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two queries that I need to compare.

I have one query (finding customers in a state) that ends up with this schema and about 14 databases:

```
| DatabaseName | CustomersPerDatabase | AccountID | ServerSize |
```

I have another query of customer databases enrolled in a certain program we have (about 100):

```
| DatabasesEnrolled |
```

I need to compare if the databases in a state are enrolled in the program. So my boss wanted me to add an additional column that is a boolean determining if a database is enrolled in the program. So like:

```
| DatabaseName | CustomersPerDatabase | AccountID | ServerSize | IsEnrolledinProgram |
```

I thought about using a case but all the info I saw was comparing a value to a static value (seeing if a value is over a certain number). I apologize if has already been asked and I appreciate any help you SQL wizards have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you have 2 query results that you want to join, and add another column which will be based on whether a row (DatabaseName) exist in the other table. If we will be following this logic, you can try this approach.

> Note: Improvised sample data as none is given.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 'db1' AS DatabaseName, 10 AS CustomersPerDatabase, 123 AS AccountID, 1 AS ServerSize
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db2' AS DatabaseName, 20 AS CustomersPerDatabase, 345 AS AccountID, 2 AS ServerSize
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db3' AS DatabaseName, 30 AS CustomersPerDatabase, 567 AS AccountID, 3 AS ServerSize
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db4' AS DatabaseName, 40 AS CustomersPerDatabase, 789 AS AccountID, 4 AS ServerSize
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT 'db1' AS DatabasesEnrolled
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'db3' AS DatabasesEnrolled
)
SELECT 
    tb1.*,
    IF(tb2.DatabasesEnrolled IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) as IsEnrolledinProgram
FROM CTE tb1
LEFT JOIN CTE2 tb2
ON tb1.DatabaseName = tb2.DatabasesEnrolled
```

Output:

[image]

If this is not the logic you are trying to describe, please improve your question for the community to address it accordingly, ie. sample data